# Synchronise database access from Java layer and JNI layer in an android application

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a Android App , which has multiple database access from java layer as well as from JNI layer. 
So do I need to synchronise the database access call b/w java layer and JNI layer?  If Yes How?

If I access the same database from both layers simultaneously what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

As long as those two parts of the programs use separate database connections, they also use separate transactions, and behave like two independent programs (i.e., they are automatically blocking each other, when needed).

Comment: No In my case, I am seeing different behaviour. My database is getting corrupt because of this frequent access. But when I comment this frequent access from java layer. it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you using separate database connections? Also see [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html).

Comment: Ya I have to. One is in Java and another database access in JNI layer